# Drupal: Can I avoid forwarding after content is created / saved?

Tags: drupal

Can I avoid forwarding after content is created / saved ?

I don't want to display the node after user click on "Save"

Comment: What do you want to display instead?

Comment: website front page, or back-end main page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_nodeapi/6) in a custom module you can put in a alternate behaviour when **$op == 'insert'**, as per below:

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'insert':
        drupal_goto('somewhere_else');
      break;
  }
}
```

Note: Code is off the top of my head, so take it for the concept.

Comment: While this would probably work in the requested context (node insert), there is a more generic approach that can be applied for arbitrary forms - see my separate answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

The generic approach to control the redirection after form completion is to [overwrite the forms '#redirect' value](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#redirect) in a custom [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6) implementation.